# How do you clean up the test features and solutions from the farm?

Tags: deployment

we have been playing around with sharepoint wsps and visual studio and there are lot of test files in the layout folder, coltrol templates and images folders, etc.

Also there exist wsps and features deployed to the farm. Is there any way to clear all this?

Comment: Are you using VS to deploy wsp to a site? and have you used SharePoint Mapped folders to include files?

Comment: yes VS and also powershell